# Simple cross-platform window/input C library to render raw pixel arrays

Tags: library, c, pixel-graphics

I want to make my own render library in a primitive way without using OpenGL or something like that. But I don't want to mess with platform specific window/input management. So I need a library like GLFW. But as far as I know GLFW can't render raw pixel data.

Comment: Have you tried Qt Framework? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-6

Comment: for rust I found https://github.com/robohouse-delft/show-image-rs

Answer (score 0):

[Tsoding uses SDL](https://github.com/tsoding/olive.c/blob/master/demos/vc.c) to do this:

```
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;

    {
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) return_defer(1);

        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Olivec", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (window == NULL) return_defer(1);

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        if (renderer == NULL) return_defer(1);

        Uint32 prev = SDL_GetTicks();
        bool pause = false;
        for (;;) {
            // Compute Delta Time
            Uint32 curr = SDL_GetTicks();
            float dt = (curr - prev)/1000.f;
            prev = curr;

            // Flush the events
            SDL_Event event;
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
                switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT: {
                    return_defer(0);
                } break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN: {
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE) pause = !pause;
                } break;
                }
            }

            SDL_Rect window_rect = {0, 0, vc_sdl_actual_width, vc_sdl_actual_height};

            if (!pause) {
                // Render the texture
                Olivec_Canvas oc_src = vc_render(dt);
                if (oc_src.width != vc_sdl_actual_width || oc_src.height != vc_sdl_actual_height) {
                    if (!vc_sdl_resize_texture(renderer, oc_src.width, oc_src.height)) return_defer(1);
                    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, vc_sdl_actual_width, vc_sdl_actual_height);
                }
                void *pixels_dst;
                int pitch;
                if (SDL_LockTexture(vc_sdl_texture, &window_rect, &pixels_dst, &pitch) < 0) return_defer(1);
                for (size_t y = 0; y < vc_sdl_actual_height; ++y) {
                    // TODO: it would be cool if Olivec_Canvas supported pitch in bytes instead of pixels
                    // It would be more flexible and we could draw on the locked texture memory directly
                    memcpy((char*)pixels_dst + y*pitch, oc_src.pixels + y*vc_sdl_actual_width, vc_sdl_actual_width*sizeof(uint32_t));
                }
                SDL_UnlockTexture(vc_sdl_texture);
            }

            // Display the texture
            if (SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0) < 0) return_defer(1);
            if (SDL_RenderClear(renderer) < 0) return_defer(1);
            if (SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, vc_sdl_texture, &window_rect, &window_rect) < 0) return_defer(1);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
    }
```